# jquery: find parent()*n in nested element?

Tags: jquery, select, jquery-selectors, parent

the question I could never find an answer for.

imagine I have a rather the following structure inside of a div:

```
<div class="BOX">
    <ul class="menu" role="navigation">
        </li><li><a class="btn" href="#">edit</a></li>
        <li><a class="btn" href="#">manage</a></li>
        <li><a class="btn deleteBtn" href="#">delete</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I want to `find()` `div.BOX when` I click on the `a.deleteBtn`. Since I have multiple div.BOX'es on my page I always need to find it with $(this).

so I could easily use `trigger.parent().parent().parent()` to select the element when inside of the deleteBtn-ClickHandler, but this doesn't look very nice. Is there a cleaner and better way to do so?

thank you.

Comment: Sarah's solution is correct. Additional information why you can't use `find`. `find` only searches for elements *inside* a given element. It's not for "finding" elements "outside" of an element such as parents or siblings.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

try this:

```
$(this).closest("div.BOX")
```

Comment: s/box/BOX/, but apart from that it's the way to go. +1

Answer (score 1):

or you can use `$(this).parents('div.BOX')`