# Getting a parent element for a jquery selector

Tags: jquery, parent

I have a table where each row has a CSS id like this:

```
<table>
<tr id='1'>...</tr>
<tr id='2'>...</tr>
<tr id='3'>...</tr>
</table>
```

In a row, a user can click on a particular element within a cell. I want to find the row that has been clicked on.

So for example:

```
<tr id='x'><td></td>...<td><div class='someclass'><div class='anotherclass'></div></div></td>...</tr>
```

In this case, I want to respond when the user clicks on a class='anotherclass' element. I want to get the id of the row containing this clicked element but I don't want to use $(this).parent().parent().parent().... etc. because there are multiple levels of parentage and it gets ugly.

Is there a way to get the row containing this element with using .parent() multiple times?

UPDATE: Thanks everyone. That is perfect.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jquery: find parent()*n in nested element?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7022834/jquery-find-parentn-in-nested-element)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use [`closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/):

```
$('.anotherclass').click(function () {
     alert($(this).closest('tr').prop('id'));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`closest`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/):

```
$(".anotherclass").click(function() {
    console.log($(this).closest("tr").attr("id"));
});
```

From the docs:

> Get the first element that matches the selector, beginning at the
>   current element and progressing up through the DOM tree.

Answer (score 1):

you can use this.

```
$('.anotherclass').click(function () {
     alert($(this).parents('tr').attr("id"));
});
```