# How do I get the value of a parent LI from the click of a child link?

Tags: jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Getting a parent element for a jquery selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7765931/getting-a-parent-element-for-a-jquery-selector)

I have a list of item :

```
        <div id="wrap"><ul class="thumbs noscript">
        <li id="1">
        <a class="thumb" href="photos/10-01.jpg" title="" />
        <img src="photos/10-01_thumb.jpg" alt="" />
        </a>
        <div class="caption">
        <div class="download"><a href="#" class="add2cart">Save Image</a></div>
        <div class="image-title">Titre de la photo #1</div>
        <div class="image-desc">Description de la photo #1</div>
        </div>
        </li> /* and so on with li's and different ID's... */
```

I can't get the value of the li ID, therefore, the title.
Have read and tried almost every answer on here, they won't work once I test on my site...
Any idea ? TY folks

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#wrap > ul > li > .caption > .download > .add2cart").click(function(){
        var thisID = $(this).closest('li').attr("id");
        alert(thisID);
    });
});
```

RIGHT ANSWER (see below) : insomiac, tyvm
And thanks also to  Diodeus for pointing out ID problem.
Thanks to all the folks who answered ;)

Comment: Is your code running before document ready? [What _have_ you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: BTW: IDs cannot start with numbers.

Comment: Raw JavaScript or jQuery?

Comment: @Diodeus ... _if the doctype of the page is not HTML5_.

Comment: It may sound trivial but, are you sure that jQuery is correctly loaded on your site ?

Comment: it is, as I have 2 other scripts running as well :) could have been though :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store the value using "data" api and then on click retrieve that value instead of using id.

```
<li id="img" data-val="1">
            <a class="thumb" href="photos/10-01.jpg" title="" />
            <img src="photos/10-01_thumb.jpg" alt="" />
            </a>
            <div class="caption">
            <div class="download"><a href="#" class="add2cart">Save Image</a></div>
            <div class="image-title">Titre de la photo #1</div>
            <div class="image-desc">Description de la photo #1</div>
            </div>
    </li> /* and so on with li's and different ID's... */
```

jquery :

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        // if you want the value of li, using the child click.
        // Do something like this, if you want the click on "thumb".
        $('.thumb').click(function(e){
             e.preventDefault();
            var val = $(this).closest('li').data('val');
         });

     });
```

Works on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MUBHF/)

Update to your js code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".add2cart").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        // Use prop if your jquery version is above 1.6.. 
        var thisID = $(this).closest('li').prop("id");
        alert(thisID);
    });
});
```

Note : As of jQuery 1.6, the .attr() method returns undefined for attributes that have not been set. In addition, .attr() should not be used on plain objects, arrays, the window, or the document. To retrieve and change DOM properties, use the .prop() method.

Comment: no error in firebug, but no value...

Comment: works for me on jsfiddle.  could you try with my updated code. ?

Comment: works for me on jsfiddle too ! but no error and no alert and no value when running on my site :((( is it possible that another script is screwing this ? PS: I'm using jquery 1.8.3

Comment: How are you loading your js file ?

Comment: not loaded but hard-coded

Comment: could you provide more info about html and jquery ? so that i can help you.

Comment: short night :) Can't put all the code here, u want to see the page on my site ?

Comment: test page : http://goo.gl/UL4uh

Comment: where is the code ? i can't find it..

Comment: look for function add2cart(){

Comment: Do this in add2cart function.. $('.thumbs li.selected').prop('id').
As add2cart is a save image and its not able to detect "li" and thats why it is giving you undefined value.

Comment: OMG ! coulda tried for **** 100 more hours and never find that solution !!! THANK YOU so much, you nailed it :)

Comment: no prob.  I am happy that i am able to solve your issue. :).
And this question is not duplicate..

Comment: I guessed so, coz the problem is so much more different from the other answers & older posts... anyway... :) Now, I have to catch values of div like image-title, let's go back to code :p

Comment: var thisTitle  = $('.thumbs li.selected').children('.image-title').html(); /* doesn't allow to access the div ? */ or is there a better way, like using closest to go up, then next, down to the children ?

Answer (score 0):

For your particular case you can use `$(this).parent().attr('id')`:

```
$('li a').on('click', function () {
   alert('you clicked a link within a li with id=' + $(this).parent().attr('id')); 
   } 
);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8QZ2s/

Comment: nope, doesn't work with me :(((((

Answer (score 0):

You can also use .closest

```
$(this).closest('li').attr('id');
```

This will ensure that it is in fact finding the li and not another parent element, should your control get nested further.